# Mac Pro reboots after sleeping with new SSD

Tags: hardware, ssd, sleep-wake, mac-pro

I have an old 2008 Mac Pro ([MacPro3,1](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_pro/specs/mac-pro-eight-core-2.8-2008-specs.html)) which I recently upgraded with a new SSD from [OWC](https://www.owcdigital.com/products/ssd/owc-ssd-electra6g-overview) (currently in Bay 4).  I transfered my OS to that drive, and ever since the computer reboots instead of waking up from sleep.

I can put it to sleep just fine, but every time it wakes (whether thorough input or timer), I get the startup chime and it goes through the (immensely faster!) boot process.

Needless to say, this is rather annoying. What can I try to fix (or at least diagnose) this problem?  I'm currently still running 10.9.5, and would prefer not to update, but I'm willing to do so if that's a likely fix.

Comment: Did you enable TRIM support?

Comment: @Allan - No, the drive [claims](https://www.owcdigital.com/products/ssd/owc-ssd-electra6g-overview) to *specifically* not need it.